# code works on dev pc but not server

Tags: asp.net, inline

The below code correctly processes data for my gridview on my dev machine but not my server.

I am simply trying to add hours to a time parameter that appears in the gridview. It works fine on my dev PC, but posts this error on server....

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is the code for the template field in my gridview...

```
<ItemTemplate> 
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("eventTime").ToString).AddHours(-5)) %>' ></asp:Label> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

How can I check for Null with inline code?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strange that it would only error out on the server. Are you able to catch the "eventTime" variable to see what it's passing through?

Comment: Well, there are NULLs but the dev set up handles them, Web server does not. Most other records are time in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a data issue between local dev and the server; I would check what is being pushed to `eventTime`. I bet it is not a valid `DateTime`.

**EDIT**

Per your edit, you can use the ternary operator (`?:`) to perform an inline null check:

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eventTime") != null ? String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("eventTime").ToString).AddHours(-5)) : "No time specified" %>' ></asp:Label>`

Comment: Well, there are NULLs but the dev set up handles them, Web server does not.